# Saving a file on OSX through Java on Android

Tags: java, android, macos, file

I am trying to write a String to a file using MacOS. This is my code:

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        File newTextFile = new File("/Users/myusername/Documents/bitmapencoded.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
        fw.write(data);
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException iox) {
        //do stuff with exception
        iox.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get a "File or directory not found" exception. Is is because Java might not have permission to write that file?

If it doesn't have permission to write in the user: Where else could I save the file (I am very new to using OSX)?

Comment: At least to me it's unclear how exactly you are combining android and osx.

Comment: Unless you're somehow making your android device aware of the presence of your OSX disk, there's no obvious way to me to achieve that. Note that `/Users/.../` is an unknown path on your android device. Why do you actually want to write on the OSX disk? If this is for debugging purposes, then you should probably write elsewhere on the device. There are ways to run command lines on OSX to be performed by the device.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I saved it on the device and sent it to my   mac via email :)

Comment: @ okiharaherbst If you edit your previous answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a "File or directory not found"

As the exception suggests, try adding:

```
if (!newTextFile.exists()) {
    newTextFile.createNewFile();
}
```

before `FileWriter fw = ...`

Comment: I created the file manually, so it should exist. I'll still try your approach :)

Comment: @deimos1988 ah! you just edited your post to add _Android_. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want a String file I create on the phone to be written in a file on the osx filesystem.

Comment: @deimos1988 So let get this straight: you're writing an Android app that you're running on an emulator or on an Android virtual machine within OSX and want to write to a file on the OSX disk, right?